# ViewPager NullPointerException while modifying FragmentActivity in Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm trying to modify an old FragmentActivity hosting a view pager with 3 listview in a Fragment. 
The Fragment class has code that is similar to an Activity. In fact, when converting an existing Android application to use fragments, I though it would have been sufficient to  move code from the activity's callback methods into the respective callback methods of the fragment. But it didn't work. I get a NullPointerException at the line

```
mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
```

here is the code:

```
public class FragmentAllEvents extends Fragment implements ActionBar.TabListener 
{
    AppSectionsPagerAdapter mAppSectionsPagerAdapter;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_UID = "uid";
    private static final String TAG_LOGO = "logo";
    private static final String TAG_POKUID = "pokuid";

    static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userListTotal;
    HashMap<String, String> userSelected;
    EventsFunctions eventsFunctions;
    UserFunctions userFunctions;
    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will display the three primary sections of the app, one at a
     * time.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;
    static ListView lv;
    ActionBar actionBar;

    //Context context = this;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.all_events_main, container, false);

        Log.e("AllEventsFragmentActivity Report", "Entering AllEventsFragments");
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        //FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mAppSectionsPagerAdapter = new AppSectionsPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());

        // Set up the action bar.
        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();

        // Specify that the Home/Up button should not be enabled, since there is no hierarchical
        // parent.
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        // Specify that we will be displaying tabs in the action bar.
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set up the ViewPager, attaching the adapter and setting up a listener for when the
        // user swipes between sections.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager_main);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mAppSectionsPagerAdapter);
        // Defining a listener for pageChange 
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() 
        {
            [...]
        });

        [...]
}
```

In the previous version of this class I was extending FragmentAllEvents with a FragmentActivity instead of a Fragment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears like, mViewPager is not populated and is NULL. If `pager_main` is in `all_events_main` layout, you need to use `v.findViewById(R.id.pager_main)`